# Comparing three columns and output as 1 or 0

Tags: r

`

```
a <- c("11-12", "22-22", "11-33")
b <- c("33-22", "33-22", "44-33")
c <- c("15-66", "33-54", "22-66")
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Hi I have a dataframe like this and want to compare the three columns using specific substring along the rows and give me a new column with the logical answer as 1 or zero for specific substring.
Meaning it should first see in the first column first row "11", then in second column first row "33" and then third column "66". if it satisfies all the three column it should give result as 1 in new column, later it should do it for all the rows.

the new column result should be like 1, 0,1

Kindly let me know if any one has answer for this, thank you very much.

Comment: Should the result be 1,0,1? I don't see how you get a result with four values if you only have three rows.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Could you please elaborate, as to what substring should be selected from every row? Because in the first column you select the first two digits (11) in the second the first two digits again (33) and in the 3rd the last two digits (66). Is there a pattern here?

Comment: Ya correct, that is the pattern and it should check , means in first row it should check only 11 if present, second only 33 if present, and third column only 66 if present if satisfies should give result as 1, else zero in new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
a <- c("11-12", "22-22", "11-33")
b <- c("33-22", "33-22", "44-33")
c <- c("15-66", "33-54", "22-66")
dat <- data.table(a,b,c)

dat[, newcol := 0]
dat[a %like% "11" & b %like% "33" & c %like% "66", newcol := 1]

#        a     b     c newcol
# 1: 11-12 33-22 15-66      1
# 2: 22-22 33-22 33-54      0
# 3: 11-33 44-33 22-66      1
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If that worked, please consider accepting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
as.integer(apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) grepl("11", x[1]) & 
         grepl("33", x[2]) & grepl("66", x[3])))
#[1] 1 0 1
```

---

Or with `Reduce` and `Map`

```
as.integer(Reduce(`&`, Map(grepl,  c(11, 33, 66), df)))
#[1] 1 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, its working but its checking 11|33|66 either of them, but I wanted to check specifically 11 in column 1, 33 in column 2 and 66 in column 3, id satisfies gives me 1 else 0. Hope I am able to explain, so i was thinking to use iflese condition.